# Executing multiple cassandra scripts on same keyspace

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

To execute a single cassandra sript through cqlsh, I am executing the below script and it is working just fine  :

```
cqlsh -k mykeyspace -u username -p password  -f file1.cql
```

But , I have multiple cqlfiles , So I created a master cql file with entries like

```
master.cql 
 --Content
source file1.cql
source files.cql
source file3.cql
```

When executing the above script :

```
cqlsh -k mykeyspace -u username -p password  -f master.cql
```

I am getting an error message like  "No Keyspace has been specified".
I don't want to hardcode the keyspace in the individual cql file. `What is the way to execute multiple cql files at once ?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-f`  switch allows only single file as of cassandra 3.0.

To run multiple files using cql shell you can create a shell file in linux and execute it.

Example:

You can create a shell file below and run it.

```
cqlsh -k mykeyspace -u username -p password  -f file1.cql
cqlsh -k mykeyspace -u username -p password  -f file2.cql
cqlsh -k mykeyspace -u username -p password  -f file3.cql
```

so instead of `master.cql` `master.sh` with above commands should do the trick.